# Given some conditions, show that $\left(1+\frac{2}{10}\right)^{10}-3^{10/6}<0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

> Given that $$\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^n\geqslant\frac{19}{3}-\frac{6}{n}\quad\text{for} \quad n\in\mathbb{N},n\geqslant 3$$ and that $\sqrt 3<\frac{7}{4}$ and $\sqrt[6] 3 >\frac{6}{5}$, show that
> $$\left(1+\frac{2}{10}\right)^{10}-3^{10/6}<0.$$

**My attempt:**

Let $n=10$. It is then clear from the first given inequality that
$$\left(1+\frac{2}{10}\right)^{10}\geqslant \frac{19}{3}-\frac{6}{10}=\frac{86}{15}.$$
Also,
$$-3^{10/6}=-3\times\sqrt{3}\times \sqrt[6] 3.$$
This is where I start to get stuck. Using $\sqrt 3<\frac{7}{4}$, we can see that
$$-3\times\sqrt{3}\times \sqrt[6] 3>-\frac{21}{4}\times \sqrt[6] 3$$ which doesn't seem to help much. Alternatively, using $\sqrt[6] 3 >\frac{6}{5}$, we can see that
$$-3\times\sqrt{3}\times \sqrt[6] 3<-\frac{18}{5}\times\sqrt 3$$
which also seems not to help. Even if we were to show that $3^{10/6}$ is greater than $86/15$ I don't see how that would help as we wouldn't know if it is smaller than
$$\left(1+\frac{2}{10}\right)^{10}$$ or not.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: They’re trying to throw you off with the extra information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about
$$\left(1+\frac{2}{10}\right)^{10}-3^{10/6}=\left(\frac{12}{10}\right)^{10}-\left(3^{1/6}\right)^{10}<\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)^{10}-\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)^{10}=0$$
The first inequality you are given is in the wrong direction to do any good here.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!